# Laptop freezes and sound loops

Tags: linux, ubuntu, manjaro

My laptop sometimes freezes with looping sound. I hadn't this problem when I was using windows. But after switching to linux(ubuntu), it started to freeze. Then i tried to switch to another linux distro(manjaro), but it didn't try and i still have this problem. It is freezing randomly. Most of the time I was just watching youtube.

My laptop settings:

```
Operating System: Manjaro Linux

KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.9

KDE Frameworks Version: 5.111.0

Qt Version: 5.15.11

Kernel Version: 6.5.9-1-MANJARO (64-bit)

Graphics Platform: X11

Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics

Memory: 7,1 GiB of RAM

Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon Graphics

Manufacturer: LENOVO

Product Name: 82KD

System Version: Lenovo V15 G2 ALC
```

Memory when freezed:
[image: Memory when freezed]

Comment: when it happens is it possible to execute a command in terminal - `free -h`? and paste here the result.

Comment: laptop completely freezes and all i can do is hold power button to shutdown. it doesn't respond to either keyboard or mouse. screen is static

Comment: then maybe it is possible to catch a moment before it happens - just to see what is with memory? I suppose it is not short youtube videos, or is it? Open some video you know it will probably cause a problem and after nn minutes execute the command in terminal.

Comment: alright, I will make this command on autorun every 2 seconds and wait until laptop completely freezes or i find other solution

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: There are some issues with that card in newer kernels, for example [this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/5857#note_1305266) or [these](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2193110#c10). Things to try: downgrade kernel to 5.x, or check if you can install the proprietary drivers (if they exist). There is also a boot parameter to set that helps in some cases, but I don't remember it.

Comment: @Andra got again this problem but with memory space in terminal

Comment: but no swap, look what @waltinator says